# Flutter Wrap is not working with large text

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I need some help to create a serie of sequential widgets, one after one, when the first ends, it comes the other directly.

> **I tried to use Wrap, but the Text is long and it takes more than the full width, so the other widget goes under the Text, not after it, even that there is space after the Text**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Testee extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TesteeState createState() => _TesteeState();
}

class _TesteeState extends State<Testee> {
  String loremOne =
      "Nostrud cillum ea do sit eu sint reprehenderit est tempor amet. Ex minim cupidatat exercitation officia mollit occaecat dolor sint sit aliqua dolore velit exercitation duis. Eu cupidatat pariatur aliquip aliquip ipsum sint ad ullamco irure eiusmod velit mollit ut elit.";

  String loremTwo = "Fugiat aute eu tempor et consequat nulla.";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Wrap(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                spacing: 10.0,
                children: [
                  Text(loremOne),
                  Icon(Icons.circle, size: 16),
                  Text(loremOne),
                  Icon(Icons.circle, size: 16),
                  Text(loremTwo),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image to understand the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8S09.jpg)

Comment: use `RichText` widget - it has `InlineSpan` where you can put your text and icons

Comment: it works thank you

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `Wrap` is not to use to separate text, but `Wrap` used to separate widgets.

As @pskink said in the comment. You need `RichText` to create your widget like your shown image.

I make a comparison beetween `Wrap` and `RichText`. May you can try this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Testee extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TesteeState createState() => _TesteeState();
}

class _TesteeState extends State<Testee> {
  String loremOne =
      "Nostrud cillum ea do sit eu sint reprehenderit est tempor amet. Ex minim cupidatat exercitation officia mollit occaecat dolor sint sit aliqua dolore velit exercitation duis. Eu cupidatat pariatur aliquip aliquip ipsum sint ad ullamco irure eiusmod velit mollit ut elit.";

  String loremTwo = "Fugiat aute eu tempor et consequat nulla.";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Wrap(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                spacing: 10.0,
                children: [
                  Text(loremOne),
                  Icon(Icons.circle, size: 16),
                  Text(loremOne),
                  Icon(Icons.circle, size: 16),
                  Text(loremTwo),
                ],
              ),
              //may you can compare your wrap with Richtext below
              RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(children: [
                TextSpan(text: loremOne),
                WidgetSpan(child: Icon(Icons.circle, size: 16)),
                TextSpan(text: loremOne),
                WidgetSpan(child: Icon(Icons.circle, size: 16)),
                TextSpan(text: loremTwo),
              ]))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro, it's exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use the **AutoSizeText** `package`, it is very useful!